# Exporting SCSS file from a npm package

Tags: angular, sass, webpack

I'm writing an Angular 2 app. I separated a component from this app to its own npm package called say `ng2-wizard`. This package contains my compoennt's code AND its styles in SCSS file `wizard.scss`.

- Now I want to include this SCSS styles in my angular component as `styleUrls` or `styles` or something, but
- I want my **app's** webpack to convert this scss into css so that the app coder can override the SCSS variables of my component, if needed.
- I don't want any webpack stuff in my `ng2-wizard` package, unless that's the only way to solve this.

I tried including the scss file in my component using these two ways:

```
// 1
import './wizard.scss';

// 2
@Component({
  // some component stuff...
  styles: [require('./wizard.scss')],
})
```

but in both cases webpack complains: `Cannot find module wizard.scss`. I suppose I have to `export` the SCSS file from my npm package somehow to my app, but how?

---

Edit:

I tried a little more digging into it.

After adding:

```
styleUrls: ['wizard.scss'],
```

to my component I get following error in console.

```
../ng2-wizard/src/wizard/wizard.scss
Module parse failed: <my-project-dir>/ng2-wizard/src/wizard/wizard.scss Unexpected token (1:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:15)
```

So I guess the question is now: How do I tell webpack to compile all *scss* files in my module?

---

Ok. From previous error (note the `../ng2-wizard`) I figured the problem was that I used `npm link` to develop my npm-packaged component so my webpack loaders configuration didn't match the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to just require your SCSS file directly in your app. If it's packaged with the ng2-wizard module, simply do the following in your code:

```
import 'ng2-wizard/wizard.scss';
```

That's it! Webpack will pick it up and add it to your bundle. You don't have to reference `wizard.scss` anywhere in the code of your ng2-wizard module.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (and rubberducking). I wanted to keep my scss stuff within my component, just enable overriding the variables in there. Turned out the problem was elsewhere so guess I'll remove this question later as it just got a bit messy =/

Comment: @kub1x, can you share your solution?